# What is "this" bound to in a frame script?

Tags: actionscript-3, this

On a frame script in ActionScript 3, what is the special variable `this` bound to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` on a framescript is bound to the MovieClip. ActionScript 3 doesn't share the dynamic `this` scoping of JavaScript, it will always be bound to the class.